# <a> value wont show when page was loaded

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

so I am quite new with development and I am testing stuff and create a sample dashboard. I am having trouble with my **sidebar value not showing when the page was load up**. I still need to click a list on my sidebar before it will show.

I have this code:

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
              aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab"
              aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
</div>
```

With a value that will just show a google map on dashboard:

```
    <div class="card">
                <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                      <div id="map-container" class="z-depth-1-half map-container" style="height: 500px">
                        <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJY96HXyFTQDIRV9opeu-QR3g&key=AIzaSyBw3Knhnxg7gMlCa5VQmnQ2P8C7N3t-zwg" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
                </div>
</div>
```

The iframe will show but the map will not until I click the dashboard section on my side bar.
Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: The map is showing for me.  Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/q182wnbk/3/).  Is there any javascript interacting with the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the `show` class to the collapsible element that you want to show by default.

Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">

    <!-- Add show class to element below -->
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">

      <div id="map-container" class="z-depth-1-half map-container" style="height: 500px">
        <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJY96HXyFTQDIRV9opeu-QR3g&key=AIzaSyBw3Knhnxg7gMlCa5VQmnQ2P8C7N3t-zwg" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh hey that works! I must've missed this one while reviewing the code. haha Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it answers the question. :)